# How to get a complete row data from VTS?

Tags: performance, loadrunner, vtable, vugen

I am using VTS tables for passing data from 1 script to other. Now, I want to get data from all the column for particular row and print that.

I tried couple of VTC commands but unfortunately that did not work.
Command I tried:- 
rc = lrvtc_query_row(vuser);
lr_output_message("Col1:- %s", lr_eval_string("{Col1}"));

can you please suggest where I got wrong or provide me a ready code to print he Row from the VTS table.

Comment: If you need to retrieve multiple values at the same time, have you considered placing them on the queue all together in one field such as "<value 1>|<value 2>|<value 3>|...."  Then when you pull the data you can then use your own separator to break apart the string to assign to your variables.  I prefer strtok() for this. Your preference may differ.

Comment: Try this: lrvtc_retrieve_messages1 ( char *columnNames, char *delimiter );

Answer (score 0):

First you have to enable API access by click the "Enable" button from VTS Web Admin page, then here's the sample:

```
Action()
{
    char* vts_ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int vts_port = 8888;
    char **colNames = NULL;
    char **rowData = NULL;      
    int row_index = 1;
    int i;

    PVCI2 pvci = vtc_connect(vts_ip, vts_port, VTOPT_KEEP_ALIVE );
    vtc_query_row(pvci, row_index,  &colNames, &rowData);

    for(i=0; colNames && colNames[i]; ++i){
        lr_output_message("%s: %s", colNames[i],  rowData[i]);
    }

    vtc_free_list(colNames);
    vtc_free_list(rowData);

return 0;
}
```